# inotify with signal implementation - linux, c++

Tags: c++, linux, signals, inotify

I want to implement in my linux c++ application, inotify with signal. I want my application to retrive an event when there is a change in a file. (without polling)

from inotify man page:

Since Linux 2.6.25, signal-driven I/O notification is available for inotify
       file descriptors; see the discussion of F_SETFL (for setting the O_ASYNC
       flag), F_SETOWN, and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2).  The siginfo_t structure (described
       in sigaction(2)) that is passed to the signal handler has the following fields
       set: si_fd is set to the inotify file descriptor number; si_signo is set to
       the signal number; si_code is set to POLL_IN; and POLLIN is set in si_band.

I didn't understand how to do it, can you please send me a sample?

10!

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the signal approach? The most common way to use inotify is to `select` or `poll` the file descriptor. If you have a long running application you are likely to call these functions anyway and all you need to do is pass them the additional inotify file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mix of TLPI code. The inotify API from [listing 19-1](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/inotify/demo_inotify.c.html) and signal-driven I/O from [listing 63-3](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/altio/demo_sigio.c.html).

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>


static int inotifyFd;


static void displayInotifyEvent(struct inotify_event *i)
{
    printf("    wd =%2d; ", i->wd);
    if (i->cookie > 0)
        printf("cookie =%4d; ", i->cookie);

    printf("mask = ");
    if (i->mask & IN_ACCESS)        printf("IN_ACCESS ");
    if (i->mask & IN_ATTRIB)        printf("IN_ATTRIB ");
    if (i->mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE) printf("IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE ");
    if (i->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)   printf("IN_CLOSE_WRITE ");
    if (i->mask & IN_CREATE)        printf("IN_CREATE ");
    if (i->mask & IN_DELETE)        printf("IN_DELETE ");
    if (i->mask & IN_DELETE_SELF)   printf("IN_DELETE_SELF ");
    if (i->mask & IN_IGNORED)      printf("IN_IGNORED ");
    if (i->mask & IN_ISDIR)      printf("IN_ISDIR ");
    if (i->mask & IN_MODIFY)        printf("IN_MODIFY ");
    if (i->mask & IN_MOVE_SELF)  printf("IN_MOVE_SELF ");
    if (i->mask & IN_MOVED_FROM)    printf("IN_MOVED_FROM ");
    if (i->mask & IN_MOVED_TO)    printf("IN_MOVED_TO ");
    if (i->mask & IN_OPEN)        printf("IN_OPEN ");
    if (i->mask & IN_Q_OVERFLOW)    printf("IN_Q_OVERFLOW ");
    if (i->mask & IN_UNMOUNT)      printf("IN_UNMOUNT ");
    printf("\n");

    if (i->len > 0)
        printf("        name = %s\n", i->name);
}

#define BUF_LEN (10 * (sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1))

static void sigio_handler(int sig)
{
    char buf[BUF_LEN] __attribute__ ((aligned(8)));

    ssize_t numRead = read(inotifyFd, buf, BUF_LEN);
    if (numRead == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "read() from inotify fd returned 0!");
    }

    if (numRead == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "read");
    }

    printf("Read %ld bytes from inotify fd\n", (long) numRead);

    /* Process all of the events in buffer returned by read() */

    for (char *p = buf; p < buf + numRead; ) {
        struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *) p;
        displayInotifyEvent(event);
        p += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
        printf("%s pathname...\n", argv[0]);

    inotifyFd = inotify_init();              /* Create inotify instance */
    if (inotifyFd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "inotify_init");
    }

    /* Establish handler for "I/O possible" signal */

    struct sigaction sa;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sa.sa_handler = sigio_handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGIO, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "sigaction");
    }

    /* Set owner process that is to receive "I/O possible" signal */

    if (fcntl(inotifyFd, F_SETOWN, getpid()) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fcntl(F_SETOWN)");
    }

    /* Enable "I/O possible" signaling and make I/O nonblocking
       for file descriptor */

    int flags = fcntl(inotifyFd, F_GETFL);
    if (fcntl(inotifyFd, F_SETFL, flags | O_ASYNC | O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fcntl(F_SETFL)");
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
        int wd = inotify_add_watch(inotifyFd, argv[j], IN_ALL_EVENTS);
        if (wd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "inotify_add_watch");
        }

        printf("Watching %s using wd %d\n", argv[j], wd);
    }

    while (1) {
        pause();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```