# Monitor file contents without looping

Tags: c, linux, embedded, embedded-linux, libuv

I need to monitor a file for any changes that may occur, meaning if some data is written into it or if the content in it is changed by someone. I need to implement this on Linux without waiting in any kind of loop .i.e I need to get notified whenever the file content changes via a callback function or something of that sort. I did try monitoring a file using libuv, however I was only able to read the contents of the file once. I have posted the code below. I was able to continuously monitor the file by using a while loop in the main function, but this is something that I am trying to avoid. Can someone please help me regarding this?

EDIT: Can anyone suggest a way by which I can change the following code to get a callback every-time the input file is modified ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <uv.h>

static uv_fs_t openReq;
static uv_fs_t readReq;
static uv_fs_t closeReq;
static uv_buf_t uvBuf;
static char strBuf[65];
static char dataBuf[64];

static void onRead(uv_fs_t *req);

static void readData(void)
{
    memset(strBuf, 0, sizeof(strBuf));
    memcpy(strBuf, dataBuf, sizeof(dataBuf));
    fprintf(stdout, "got some data: %s\n", strBuf);
    memset(dataBuf, 0, sizeof(dataBuf));
    uv_fs_read(uv_default_loop(), &readReq, openReq.result, &uvBuf, 1, -1, onRead);
}

static void onRead(uv_fs_t *req)
{
    uv_fs_req_cleanup(req);
    if (req->result < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", uv_strerror(req->result));
    } else if (req->result == 0) {
        uv_fs_close(uv_default_loop(), &closeReq, openReq.result, NULL);
    } else {
        readData();
    }
}

static void onOpen(uv_fs_t *req)
{
    if (req->result < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", uv_strerror(req->result));
    } else {
        uvBuf = uv_buf_init(dataBuf, sizeof(dataBuf));
        uv_fs_read(uv_default_loop(), &readReq, req->result, &uvBuf, 1, -1, onRead);
    }
    uv_fs_req_cleanup(req);
}


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uv_fs_open(uv_default_loop(), &openReq, argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0, onOpen);
    return uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: If you are doing on linux you can try inotify :)

Comment: @Horacio : I had done some research using inotify, but i think it requires a loop. let me try again

Comment: @poseidon From a (very) quick scan of the [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) man-page, it _will_ require a loop to repeatedly acquire events by using `read()` on the inotify file-descriptor (see 3rd bullet point under _Description_), but that `read()` should block until there is an event to report, and won't be "wasting" CPU. If your program needs to do other things while waiting for events, you might need to use threads or something like [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to see if there is an event pending.

Comment: @poseidon Everything requires a loop. Your code in the question has a loop. But the loop is inside libuv. You can make libuv work with inotify.

Comment: Apparently, you can use signals (and hence a callback mechanism) — see [`inotify(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) and [inotify with signal implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078345/inotify-with-signal-implementation-linux-c).  Be cautious about what you do in the signal handler, that's all.